# How to access the data within a subfolder, when my main script is also in a subfolder?

Tags: python

[image]

Hello, so I have a jupyter notebook in the data/processed folder and I want to access the json and csv file I have downloaded into the data/raw folder. I can't seem to write the correct path for it.

```
data\
  processed\
    datacleaning.ipynb
  raw\
      getdata.ipynb
      EXAMPLE.json
      EXAMPLE.csv
src\
  results.ipynb
```

```
import pandas as pd
import json

raw_data = open("./data/raw/EXAMPLE.json")
```

i got the FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './data/raw/EXAMPLE.json'

Anyone know what the correct path would be?

Comment: Depends on what `os.getcwd()` returns. Your current working directory and your source directory don't have anything to do with each other unless you go out of your way to make it so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume your project lives in the absolute folder `/home/karo/projects/`.
Your notebooks current directiory is `/home/karo/projects/data/processed`.

When you write

```
raw_data = open("./data/raw/EXAMPLE.json")
```

it will be resolved to

```
raw_data = open("/home/karo/projects/data/processed/data/raw/EXAMPLE.json")
```

As you can see that's not an existing path.

You can either write:

- `raw_data = open("/home/karo/projects/data/raw/EXAMPLE.json")`
- `raw_data = open("../raw/EXAMPLE.json")`

Comment: Yes, _but_ we already have answered questions telling people how to find the location of the IPython Notebook being used, and how to calculate relative paths. Better to point them that way than to add a new answer that boils down to saying "it's your responsibility to either provide an absolute path or know a path relative to the current CWD".

Comment: thank you!, i was trying  everything but the "../"